# Propagate Schema and Code Changes Across Multiple Databases

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design, schema

I am working on a Sql Server 2012 Express and have multiple duplicate databases that serve an application. One of the project requirements is to have data separation between clients due to various business and government laws.

Due to upgrades and bug fixes we have to make table schema changes or updates to the stored procedures, functions, and views. It has not been a huge problem updating every database individually because there are around a dozen, but in the foreseeable future we will be adding more databases.

What options are available for me to propagate the changes to all databases without having to touch each one? My biggest concern is skipping a database accidentally and the time involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google for "database versioning".

RedGate have a [product](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-source-control/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_content=non-brand&utm_campaign=sqlsourcecontrol&gclid=Cj0KEQjw8aeiBRCknPXk-u_V_4gBEiQAD2-mgY8jaayKrIG0Y1pivgZ7pzTgxN9eJi6l57Lqc_jTwFMaAuct8P8HAQ) specifically for SQL Server - it's pretty good, especially as the complexity of your solution increases.

[Here](http://www.infoq.com/articles/db-versioning-scripts)'s a pretty decent article explaining the concept.

In broad, simple terms:

- Put your database change scripts in source control, using a naming
  convention that allows a script to reason about them. For instance,
  start the name with a number which allows the script to say "run them
  in numerical ascending order".
- in a script - e.g. your build and deployment script - execute the database scripts in ascending order. Typically, you want to keep track of which database scripts you have run on each environment (e.g. "dev", "test" and "production"). Only execute the ones you haven't already run.
- when provisioning a new environment, run all scripts, in numerical order.
- for optional extra sanity, couple your database scripts to a software version (e.g. app version 12.4 depends on database scripts up to 101). This allows you to push software changes through environments with their corresponding database versions.

Comment: Excellent answer for my question. Redgate costs a little bit but the time saved and reduced mistakes potential makes it look worthwhile.